# How to find if a point is within a contour defined by a 2D unstructured grid in VTK?

Tags: c++, vtk

In my current problem, I want to be able to detect when a point is within a 2D vtkUnstructuredGrid or not.

I have tried using vtkSelectEnclosedPoints by making a vtkGeometryFilter and using it on my unstructuredGrid. However, the vtkSelectEnclosedPoints class is designed to check if points are located within a surface, not within a contour. Thus, when I try to apply it in 2D, I find that my points are outside of my mesh even though I know that they are located inside. This is because the class inherently works in 3D.
Is there a similar class or approach I could use to detect when points are within a 2D vtkUnstructuredGrid? The code is able to know the dimension of the mesh before opening it (it is a user input).

Answer (score 1):

So all the points in your "contour" vtkUnstructuredGrid form a single polygon? In that case you could use the vtkPolygon class, see example [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/PointInPolygon). If your unstructured grid is multiple polygons, then I would still use the same thing, just iterated over all the polygons.

Comment: All the points in the contour of my vtkUnstructuredGrid form a weird concave geometry that changes with each run of my software. Since this geometry is constitued from a number of polygon that can also change from time to time, I don't see how I could reconstruct these polygons each time?

Comment: The PointInPolygon function works with concave polygons as well, so that is not a problem. If as you say the geometry is multiple polygons, just test all the polygons using the PointInPolygon function from the example until you find one within which the point is (or until you test all if it isn't within any of them). If this solution is not what you are looking for, perhaps some screenshot or code snippet would illustrate your problem better...How is the boundary that you want to test defined if not as a (set of) polygon(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a vtkModifiedBSPTree based on your 2D grid and perform raycasting (IntersectWithLine) for the points you want to test. I have used this class for terrain models triangulated as polydata, it is extremely fast and reliable.